# Creating linq expression with a subtype restriction

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have this list of type `IEnumerable<MyBaseType>` for which I am trying to create an extra where-clause to retrieve a specific item in the list. The specific value does only exist on subtype MyFirstType and MySecondType. Not on MyBaseType.

Is it possible to create an expression kind of...

```
MyList.Where(b => (b is MyFirstType || (b is MySecondType)) && b.SpecificValue == message.SpecificValue);
```

Above is not working since b is of type MyBaseType and SpecificValue does not exist there. Also note that I do have another subtype MyThirdType that neither has the SpecificValue.

What does work doing what I want is this...

```
foreach (dynamic u in MyList)
{
    if (u is MyFirstType || u is MySecondType)
    {
        if (u.SpecificValue == message.SpecificValue)
        {
            //Extracted code goes here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to create an linq expression for the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct translation of your code to a Linq where clause is

```
string messageValue = "foo";
var result = baseList.Where(item =>
{
    dynamic c = item;
    if(item is MyFirstType || item is MySecondType)
    {
        if( c.SpecificValue == messageValue)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

This will require testing the type of the class though **and** using dynamic - so you might as well cast item to either `MyFirstType` or `MySecondType` directly.

An alternative would be using reflection to check if the property exists, using this approach you are not dependent on the actual types of your items as long as they do have the property you are interested in:

```
string messageValue = "foo";
var result = baseList.Where( item => 
    {
        var prop =  item.GetType().GetProperty("SpecificValue");
        if (prop != null && prop.GetValue(item, null) == messageValue)
            return true;
        else return false;
    });
```

If modifying the class hierarchy is an option you can have you `MyFirstType` or `MySecondType` implement an interface that holds the property, then you can use `OfType()` in your Linq query:

```
interface ISpecific
{
    string SpecificValue { get; set; }
}
class MyFirstType : MyBase, ISpecific
{
    public string SpecificValue { get; set; }
}
...
string messageValue = "foo";
var result = baseList.OfType<ISpecific>()
                     .Where(item => item.SpecificValue == messageValue);
```

Comment: I actually go for the first version with dynamic. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is a better solution but as I see it, this could work well enough... If you don't mind performance.

Well then, start by declaring an interface:

```
public interface IMySpecialType
{
   object SpecificValue {get; set;} //you didn't specify what type this is
   //all your other relevant properties which first and second types have in common
}
```

Then, make MyFirstType and MySecondType derive from this interface:

```
public class MyFirstType : MyBaseType, IMySpecialType
{
   //snipet
}

public class MyFirstType : MySecondType, IMySpecialType
{
   //snipet
}
```

Then, filter and cast:

```
MyList
    .Where(b => (b is MyFirstType) || (b is MySecondType))
    .Cast<IMySpecialType>()
    .Where(b => b.SpecificValue == message.SpecificValue);
    //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

A far more easy way to do that would be to create an interface to mark all your classes having this property **SpecificValue**. Then it's a child play :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyBaseType> MyList = new List<MyBaseType>();
        ISpecificValue message = new MyFirstType();
        MyList.OfType<ISpecificValue>().Where(b => b.SpecificValue == message.SpecificValue);
    }
}

class MyBaseType { }
interface ISpecificValue { string SpecificValue { get; set; } }
class MyFirstType : MyBaseType, ISpecificValue
{
    public string SpecificValue;
}
class MySecondType : MyBaseType, ISpecificValue
{
    public string SpecificValue;
}
```

Comment: Ooops ! I had not noticed Francisco's similar answer. I prefer mine because the built-in `OfType` seems more elegant to me than this strange combination of `Where` and `Cast` where the implementing types `MyFirstType` and `MySecondType` are hard-coded.

Comment: Noticed your answer similar to Francisco. Yes, it sure is simple but I don't want to introduce yet another interface.

Comment: I highly respect this wish. Nevertheless, I wouldn't hesitate to do so. It's how the whole .Net framework is conceived : abstraction whenever possible, interfaces rather than classes... The cost in creating this new one-liner interface is negligible, the interface's purpose is not difficult to understand (thanks to a self-explanatory name), and it garantuees the maintainability of your code. If additional classes with a **SpecificValue** property should appear in the future, you wouldn't have to modify your code to hard-code this new class in the `Where` clause test.